# phonegap build android app splashscreen not working

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, phonegap-build

I'm new to phonegap. I have an issue i couldn't figure it out in the past 2 weeks. I'm using phonegap build for a android app. The app works fine, however, the splash screen is not working. I even tried to use the mais phonegap test page, and their splash screen is not showing as well...

I've searched in all foruns, and tried to do many things... but none worked...

If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Here is my xml file.

```
 <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"  />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  />
    <gap:splash src="screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"  />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have these settings and they are now working:

```
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000"/>
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />

<platform name="android">
    <!-- you can use any density that exists in the Android project -->
    <splash src="res/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform> 

<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" />
<icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" />
<icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" />
<icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" />
```

Please note that res/drawable...... folders should be in you App level root folder with images and they will be copied automatically to platform folders.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This preference setting `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />` is telling Android that the name of your splash-screen image is `screen.png`.

Try changing `<gap:splash src="splash.png" />` to `<gap:splash src="screen.png" />`

or `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />` to `<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />`

Then for your other sizes, use different paths instead of different names.

Example:

```
<gap:splash src="screen/android/ldpi/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="screen/android/mdpi/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi"  />
<gap:splash src="screen/android/hdpi/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi"  />
<gap:splash src="screen/android/xhdpi/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi"  />
```

Comment: Still didn't work, i've created the specific folders ldpi, and changed the paths... renamed the specific files in each folder... changed to splash.png... And nothing...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a line defining the default splash screen is all.

Here is another post with similar issues: [phonegap build not showing splashscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385308/phonegap-build-not-showing-splashscreen/25410466#25410466)

Comment: I've tried... I looked all the posts here at stack and tried all of them, none worked...