# Phonegap build not showing splashscreen on android?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, splash-screen

I m adding splashscreen in config.xml file like this:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />

<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />

    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" />

    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
</platform>
```

All my splash screen are here: `res/screen/android/`. I tied with local and phonegap build but splash screen in android only not showing. iphone splash screen working fine.

Comment: I had similar problem in ionic. May be you have to search for similar command in phonegap. The issue was resolved with  (ionic resources --splash)  These will make sure all the resources are considered while building. Obviously these should be mentioned in configuration files

Comment: @Owais Kiani Check out this link - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12077 Ensure that you are using cordova-android version 6.1.0 to resolve this

Comment: See my previous answer - here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385308/phonegap-build-not-showing-splashscreen/25410466#25410466

Comment: try with this plugin     <plugin spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git"/>