# cordova phonegap splash screen not showing in android

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, splash-screen, phonegap

Here goes my code for splash Android. Still does not show the splash screen. Added codes as per the splash screen for android only but still didn't got the splash screen

```
<platform name="android">
    <!-- <splash src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="land-hdpi"/> -->
    <!-- <splash src="res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" width="640" height="960"/> -->
        <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
         <splash density="land-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/apple-touch-icon.png" />   
</platform>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385308/phonegap-build-not-showing-splashscreen

Comment: @KirankumarDafda, I tried this but didn't worked.Any other solution please